# create div dynamically and assign django form set elements

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-forms

I have a situation where, I have different items for a product and there are different products for a type. On the type page, I need to display each product and respective items of that product. I want to use bootstrap collapsible components, so when a user clicks on the product title, the div for that product can be shown with collapsible options for Items. When a user clicks on an item, the item information is displayed. I get the data in formset from django views, but I don't know how to display them in dynamic divs.

Here is my .html file to show how I want the items to be displayed.

```
<div class="panel panel-default"> <!-- Display Type -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#entities"> Products </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="entities" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel panel-default"> <!-- Display Items -->
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#item1"> Items </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="item1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <h4> Item 1 </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did u find a solution for this ?

Comment: yes. I used {{ entities.id }} as the ID of div tag and gave it in collapsible menu href. Entities here is a Django formset element. I hope this helps.

Comment: where's the formset ? (maybe you can paste your approach as a solution)